# AWS S3 and EBS backup?

Tags: backup, amazon-s3, amazon-ebs, amazon-web-services

I'm rather new to Amazon Web Services. I have a question regarding S3 and EBS. Do I have to backup an S3 or EBS service? Are these types of storage secure and backuped by amazon itself?

Comment: EBS are said to have an Annual Uptime of ~99.5%, so prepare accordingly.  S3 is much more durable at ~99.99%.  Take these into account and backup accordingly.  It would be wise if the data is very important, to plot around AWS being the point of failure.

Optimally: EBS -> Snapshot to S3 -> Offline Backup (As needed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are protected against disk crashs etc. by Amazon.

But you are **not** protected against failure from your own code e. g. overwriting data by mistake. So always have an external backup or at least store the data in two different "buckets".

> do i have to backup a s3 or ebs service aswell?

... so the answer is: yes ;-)

Comment: You are **not** protected against disk crashes by Amazon on EBS. You should expect EBS volumes to disappear into the ether. S3 is much more reliable, according to Amazon, but you'd be crazy to trust it entirely to them.

Answer (score 3):

Lost a 1 TB EBS volume today. AWS support said although this is rare it does happen.

> Your volume experienced a failure due to multiple failures of the
>   underlying hardware components and we were unable to recover it.
>   Although EBS volumes are designed for reliability, backed by multiple
>   physical drives, we are still exposed to durability risks caused by
>   concurrent hardware failures of multiple components, before our
>   systems are able to restore the redundancy. We publish our durability
>   expectations on the EBS detail page here (http://aws.amazon.com/ebs).